# ARM base SOC with ubuntu, what about the license?

Tags: arm, license, free

I work in an ARM Context-A base SOC design company.
We release the android/linux base SDK to our customers. and it can run in our SOC.
Some of our customers hope we to support ubuntu-desktop on our SOC.

If we support ubuntu-desktop on ARM base SOC,
What about the license? Is it fully free?
Can we release the ubuntu-desktop supported SDK to customer?

Comment: 1. Thoroughly analyze the licenses of all components in your SDK, including the Ubuntu packages, kernel drivers, and your own custom additions. It's easy to overlook an important licensing rule, so focus on border cases to ensure compliance. 2. Engage with Canonical to discuss the use of Ubuntu trademarks and potential compliance with their trademark guidelines. 3. Consider consulting with a lawyer specializing in open source licensing to ensure your SDK complies with all relevant licenses and avoids any legal issues.